# RD-ZD-25F, 220V/50W motor as a generator

Tags: dc, dc-motor, generator

I have 2 RD-ZD-25F, 220V/50W DC motors from 2 broken bread-making machines. Can they be used as a generator?
I gave one with the hand few spins and I got a little bit of a shock from it.

Thanks

PS: The only specs I could find for it: 
Model: RD-ZD-25F
Voltage rating: 220 VDC
Current rating: 0.23 A
Power: 50 W
Motor diameter: 63 mm
Motor length: 105 mm
Shaft diameter: Ф7 mm with jam 14 mm
Shaft length: 20 mm
Wiring: 2-way cable
Motor mounting: 3 x openings M3 mm
Body material: metal
Application: used in bakeries and ovens

Comment: I think you've already answered your question even before posting it. You gave the shaft a spin and got an electric shock - therefore yes it can be used as a generator.

Comment: Indeed, the issue is that, with a voltmeter, I get voltages from 10 to 190V (different because of different RPM) .. and how can I make it more constant (lets say 12V)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your motor is a permanent magnet DC type so yes, you can use it as a generator.

The permanent magnets create a fixed field strength. Since the voltage generated in a wire is proportional to its rate of movement through the magnetic field, the motor will produce higher voltage at higher rpm. To get constant voltage out you have two options:-

1. Spin the motor at constant rpm.

Depending on what mechanism is driving it you may be able to use a centrifugal governor, CVT or variable pitch blades to adjust the speed.

2. Regulate the output down to a lower voltage.

You could try using a switched mode power supply that is designed for eg. 90~230V input and 12V output.

Comment: Thank you! Do you know a switching regulator? (I looked on analog.com and couldn't find one with Vin max > 30V)

Comment: Look for "off-line switching regulator" or "SMPS controller". Alternatively you could modify a commercial switching power supply, or scavenge parts from an surplus device that has one in it.