# Converting 12-220V to 12V?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, switching-regulator

Are there any Analog/Maxim (I couldn't find a switching regulator with these characteristics on their websites) ICs that can step-down a voltage between 12 and 220 V (coming from a generator) to a stable 12V?

Thank you!

Comment: AC or DC? - - -

Comment: Coming from a generator, I'm guessing AC with variable voltage and frequency to match, but @Sorin would have to verify that to be sure.

Comment: @Aaron: Some "generators" include rectifiers, or are commutated to rectify.  Think of a DC brushed motor run in reverse, for example.  At the level the OP is obviously at, we really don't know what he has.

Comment: A resistor and zener could do that but you wouldn't get much current.

Comment: @Olin: That's certainly possible, with slightly increasing probability with age, but the upper voltage range suggests to me that it's a standard unit off a gas powered genset that's connected to something else like maybe a windmill.  And I suspect you're right about the OP as well.

Comment: how much power does the load require? i.e. maximum output current into the 12VDC load? And how much power is available from the source? SMPS at lower input condition must draw higher current from the source. And how much headroom is there between VinMin and Vout? if 0 you may be better off just using a relay to directly connect 12Vin to 12Vout at low input case, and use a more conventional 220V to 12V inverter otherwise.

Comment: The 12-220V voltage will come from this: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/173787/rd-zd-25f-220v-50w-motor-as-a-generator, so a DC brushed motor running in reverse.

Comment: So all of the actual power used by the 12VDC load, must be supplied by something mechanical that turns the shaft of the DC motor-generator salvaged from a bread machine. The motor is "50W" rated as a DC motor, I don't know what that means when used as a DC generator... it won't be 100% efficient, so maybe you put in 50W of mechanical power turning the shaft and get 12W of 220VDC electric power into the SMPS, then maybe if you're lucky 10-11W into the 12VDC load. So then the SMPS has to handle switching currents on the order of 1-2.5A peak, depending on how it's designed...

Comment: ...If the DC motor-generator is cranked at low RPM (generating 90VDC or less), then the SMPS has to draw a lot more current out of the generator to draw a constant power input. This is a big problem. Those big copper windings that capture the voltage, can also have I2R heat losses that are significant at high current. You're better off keeping the generator shaft spinning as fast as possible, using higher voltage reduces the current loss (and self-heating). Can you somehow determine the minimum input RPM that is required, to generate 90VDC (to supply a standard SMPS solution)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wow, this is a tough one. First, there is clearly no component that would cover the whole range. Due to huge investment that is required for an IC development, any such component is designed for specific market. Although each manufacturer will try to support as many applications as possible, nobody will invest in such small niche. I can say it's small for several reasons, and please, note all of them:

1. In all my career i did not see such requirement.
2. Applications for lower voltages are made cheaper and simpler, while for higher voltages there are special components.
3. Low and high voltage not only differ electrically. It takes very different expertise to design low and high voltage schemes, so vendors will address one of the two domains, but rarely both.
4. **This is maybe most significant consideration** rarely an electromechanical device effectively covers such wide range. Motors "feel good" in certain RPM, generators have better power output in certain RPM, etc. This is why you see gears on them, this is why for high velocity there are specially optimized motors, etc.

So first of all, check your requirements. Probably your life will be easier, if you will define simpler range, like 90V to 350V.

Practically, you will have to rectify the input (with diodes and capacitors), then most of the range will be covered by ST micro's viper. The rest may be overlaid by Onsemi or TI high voltage DC/DC.

Then you will have to select the input. It should probably be a relay that will switch the source, and some kind of low power comparator to be powered by resistor and LDO from both sources connected with diodes...

I believe, and hope that you will just drop the lower part of your input range.

Answer (score 5):

One possibility is to have a boost converter bypassed by a diode.  When the output is 95 V or above, it does nothing (the raw voltage is just passed to the output thru the diode).  When the output drops below 95 V, the boost converter runs and makes 95 V from the 12-95 V input.

Now use that to run a regular "universal input" off the shelf 12 V power supply.

However, read what Gregory said carefully.  Most likely it would be better to avoid this kind of kludge by re-thinking the overall system.

If the generator produces 240 V at full speed, then the power available when it's running so slowly to produce 12 V is probably not worth bothering to capture.  Think about what you really need carefully.  Try to see if you can transform the problem into driving a 90-240 V universal input 12 V power supply.

Answer (score 1):

In the industrial controls business, it's not unheard of to have a range of < 20VDC to >240VAC, but 12VDC might be asking a bit much-> ~20:1.

I think it could be done, with fairly miserable efficiency, by using a separate controller chip that does not enforce too low a UVLO level, but that's about as far as I can take it without specs (and even then..).

Comment: Did you mean >200:1?

Comment: @Aaron: No, 240 V to 12 V is a 20:1 ratio.

Comment: Okay, my bad.  Got my decimal shifting off.

Comment: @AaronD do you want a loan of a calculator?